# Why are there no longer Windows binaries for PECL extensions like pecl_http?

Tags: php, http, wamp, pecl, wimp

I'm working on a PHP project running on Windows and it would be so very handy to be able to use pecl_http rather than working with cURL and re-inventing the wheel in order to do all the cool stuff the pecl extension does like parsing headers and so forth.

Everywhere I read (including the PHP site) is that the Windows binary for pecl_http is no longer packaged with any PHP installation. I can't find any explanation as to why not anywhere. Also, http://pecl4win.php.net/ has been down for ages and I can only assume that the pecl4win project is dead.

Does anyone know the story about what happened and if there are any nice alternatives to pecl_http that I can run in a WIMP environment?

Comment: ... +1 just for teaching me a new acronym that I'm going to learn to love... WIMP, genious.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

> First, download the PECL module from the php website : PECL 5.2.2 Win32 binaries. 
>   Then unzipp it and copy the file `php_http.dll` in your PHP extension folder. 
> Now edit your php.ini file (c:\WINDOWS\php.ini) and activate the module : 
> **extension=php_http.dll**
>   Restart apache and check the installation using phpinfo.

**EDIT: ** Link: [PECL 5.2.6 Windows Binaries](http://www.sfr-fresh.com/windows/www/pecl-5.2.6-Win32.zip/)

[Source](http://www.art122-5.net/index.php/How_to_install_PECL_HTTP)

Comment: Hey, thanks mate. But, this is kind of how I got stuck in this situation to begin with :). I can't find the binaries anywhere and it seems the people who used to compile them for Win32 no longer do it. Frustrating huh?

Comment: From the PHP website regarding Windows version: Note: The PECL package will not be released for this version. The 5.2.6 PECL package does however work with this release

Comment: Try downloading from here: http://www.sfr-fresh.com/windows/www/pecl-5.2.6-Win32.zip/

Comment: Switched the accepted answer over to you as you've helpfully included not just where to get it, but how to configure it.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this is a fresh update to the page or if I missed it the first time. But under the current Windows Binaries there is a note which reads:

> Note: The PECL package will not be
>   released for this version. The 5.2.6
>   PECL package does however work with
>   this release

(From: http://www.php.net/downloads.php)

For some reason I only noticed the first part, to the point where I'm almost SURE the second sentence wasn't there when I checked the first time :). Not to worry, effectively this means I can use the PECL package from the 5.2.6 release of PHP.
(http://museum.php.net/php5/pecl-5.2.6-Win32.zip)

Thanks guys for your answers, it was a great help.

Cheers
Iain

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps one of the [PEAR modules](http://pear.php.net/search.php?q=http&in=packages&x=0&y=0) can help you? PEAR modules are implemented in PHP, so will work on any PHP install anywhere (theoretically).

Installation instructions for [Pyrus (PHP 5.3+)](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/installationpyrus.introduction.php) or plain old [PEAR](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/installation.php).

Comment: Oh hey it's you again! You answered my C# syntax question the other day! I love your work :)

Comment: C# and PHP are my pet languages. And yes, not having a job (damn it!) helps in the whole "troll SO" aspect of things ;)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why Windows binaries were not available for a while, but now they are back.

This is the link for the PECL extensions Windows binaries (including pecl_http):
http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/

Answer (score 0):

I found the php_http.dll on this site as well, http://downloads.php.net/pierre/ for a WAMP installation but the apache server kept throwing an exception loading the dll. But I got the apache server to start fine by loading the dll from the above link.

sfr-fresh.com/windows/www/pecl-5.2.6-Win32.zip