# IIS PHP 7.1 PECL DLL Libraries

Tags: php, iis, pecl, iis-10, php-7.1

I am running IIS 10 with PHP 7.1 and was trying to make use of the `http_parse_cookie()` method in PHP Storm when I realized that PHP Storm was only providing the stubs to the PECL methods. After an exhaustive search on the web, I came across this [**Windows PECL repository**](http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/http/) but it only goes up to 2.5.0 which doesn't work when I try to use it.

I need **php_http-3.1.0-7.1-nts-vc14-x64.zip** but the only thing they have listed is some log files. Where can I reliably get the php_http.dll for PHP 7.1?

I've done tons of searches but the DLLs are nowhere to be found.

Comment: I also tried all of the links in this other post but they were all old: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1634726/why-are-there-no-longer-windows-binaries-for-pecl-extensions-like-pecl-http

Comment: I also see Zend framework has some packages for HTTP like `zend-diactoros` but I'm not sure if one would be better/preferred over the other.